# convert request.getParameterMap() to bean

Tags: java

I want to convert `Map<String, String[]>` to a `Bean` with getters and setters. Is there a library that can do this already? If not, how can it be done?

My idea is that it would be something like this:

```
public Object convert(final Map<String, String[]> map) {
    Object object = new Object() {
    Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        Object mEntry.getKey() = mEntry.getValue();
     }
    };
    return object;
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity,why you want to do such a thing.?

Comment: What exactly is the use case here and what are you after? There are many ways in which you could do it, but it depends on how and what operation you want to perform post doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apache.commons.beanutils will map the values of map to bean if the class  already exists.

BeanUtils.populate(student, map);

Say here student class already exists.

Comment: Thank you for the above. The only problem I have is that I don't know what the object will be so `student` won't work since I'm not converting only one specific object.

Comment: I used `BeanUtils.populate(object, request.getParameterMap());` instead which worked.

Comment: student was an example i took :) You can use your own say object as you've done

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with List Of Objects

```
public List<ObjectSample> convert(final Map<String, String[]> map) {

List<ObjectSample> list = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
    ObjectSample object = new ObjectSample();
    object.setKey(mEntry.getKey()); 
    object.setValue(mEntry.getValue());
    list.add(object);
 }

return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the above. The only problem I have is that I don't know what the object will be so `ObjectSample` won't work since I'm not converting only one specific object.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the resulting POJO, you can use jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or another json/xml to POJO mapping library. Do you know what the resulting object looks like?

What Rajesh says is also a solution, which is event easier. But the same problem - you have to know the structure of the result.

Comment: Thank you for the above. I don't know what the resulting object looks like, no. I want to create the object dynamically. Perhaps Reflection could be used?